# How to insert value headers in columns?

Tags: vba, excel

The code below adds multiple columns based on the input number. How can I add a value/text from the columns that I created?

Example: If I input the number 5 it will create 5 columns. I want to add a value for that columns.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button2_Click()

    Dim iCountCols
    Dim colRef As String
    Dim colRef2 As String
    Dim colAdd As Worksheet

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set colAdd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet")
    Sheets("RDBMergeSheet").Select
    Range("M1").Select

    iCountCols = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Insert number of columns" _
    & "?", Type:=1)

    If iCountCols <= 0 Then End

    Selection.Resize(, iCountCols).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlRight

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I want to insert a value at the same time as creating the column.
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve after inserting the columns? Can you share a screenshot of before and after?

Comment: I already edited my question..Please see the attached image..Thank you!

Comment: Your edit doesn't help us understand what it is you are trying to do after inserting the columns.  What values are you trying to insert?  Just "header2", "header3" ... "header6"?  (If so, just set the `Value` to those values.)  Some user input?  (If so, use an InputBox to get the value and then set the `Value` to whatever the user entered.)  Something from another cell?  (If so, just set the `Value` to the `Value` of that cell.)

Comment: Your logic appears flawed. (1) You don't need to add columns to a worksheet. They are already there. All you need is to add a caption and perhaps format some or all cells. (2) The number of columns you wish to "add" is immaterial. The important thing is how many header captions you can enter. (2a) If you can only enter one caption you need to call the same procedure 5 times to add 5 columns. (2b) If you can enter 5 column captions in one go then you don't need to ask the number of columns. (2c) In effect the number of columns to add is always equal to the number of captions you can enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Example if I input a number 5 it will create 5 columns..I want to add a value for that columns..

If I understood good you need different value for each column, here it goes.

```
dim col_values_input as string
dim col_values() as string

col_value=InputBox("Type your column/s value bellow, delimit them with coma")
col_values=Split(col_value, ",")
if col_values.Lenght <> 0 And Not col_values.Lenght > iCountCols Then
   count = 0
   for each val in col_values
      colAdd.range("M1").offset(0,count).value=val
      count = count + 1
   next val
end if
```

add this at the end of the code, should work well.

Comment: `col_values.Lenght` ?

Comment: Thank you sir! You really helped me :)